# Calculating percentage difference between rows on table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I want to calculate the percentage difference between rows for a grouping of account number, benefit and year. I am using SQL 2008

Example BEFORE

```
AccountNbr    Benefit   Year Month Value  Diff
------------  -------   ---- ----- -----  ----
123           A         2014 11    10   
123           A         2014 12    20
123           A         2015 1     10   
123           A         2015 2     20
123           A         2015 3     40
123           B         2015 1     50
123           B         2015 2     100
123           B         2015 3     150
```

Example AFTER (what i would like to see)

```
AccountNbr    Benefit   Year Month Value  Diff
------------  -------   ---- ----- -----  ----
123           A         2014 11    10     0
123           A         2014 12    20     100
123           A         2015 1     10     -50
123           A         2015 2     20     100
123           A         2015 3     40     100   
123           B         2015 1     50     0
123           B         2015 2     90     80
123           B         2015 3     40     -55
```

Comment: What's the version on SQL Server?

Comment: Add a 2014 12 row to you example, just to make it a little bit safer.

Comment: Same as a "Running Total" only doing a percentage difference instead of a sum.

Comment: @TabAlleman: SS 2008 doesn't support running totals :-(

Comment: It's not built-in, but if you google "how to do running totals in SQL Server 2008" there are numerous examples out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in order to identify previous row within each `AccountNbr, Benefit` partition. You can then `LEFT JOIN` with the previous row and calculate the percentage difference (if that's what you really want after all!):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT AccountNbr, Benefit, Year, Month, Value,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNbr, Benefit 
                             ORDER BY Year, Month) AS rn
   FROM mytable
 )
 SELECT c1.AccountNbr, c1.Benefit, c1.Year, c1.Month, c1.Value,             
        CAST(COALESCE (((c1.Value - c2.Value) * 1.0 / c2.Value) * 100, 0) AS INT) AS Diff
 FROM CTE AS c1
 LEFT JOIN CTE AS c2 
 ON c1.AccountNbr = c2.AccountNbr AND c1.Benefit = c2.Benefit AND c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5116e6/2)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got a row for each year/month you can do a self-join:

```
select t1.*
  ,coalesce(100*(t1.value - t2.value) / t2.value, 0)
from tab as t1 
left join tab as t2
  on t1.AccountNbr = t2.AccountNbr
 and t1.Benefit = t2.Benefit
 and t1.year  = case when t2.month < 12 then t2.year else t2.year +1 end
 and t1.month = case when t2.month < 12 then t2.month +1 else 1 end
```

If a month is missing this will return zero again.